# How can i login to Azure Portal with a user that has MFA from powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to login to Azure Portal by using the simple

```
az login -u "<email>" -p "<pwd>"
```

Because users are set toi use MFA , it gives and error:

az : ERROR: AADSTS50079: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator,
you must enroll in multi-factor authentication to access

How can i allow the login or  enroll in multi-factor authentication to access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. However, you can create a security group, add the user to it and add the group to the excluded users and groups in your conditional access policy.

Create an exclusion group:

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. In the left navigation, select Azure Active Directory and then
   select Groups.
3. On the top menu, select New Group to open the group pane.
4. In the Group type list, select Security. Specify a name and
   description.
5. Make sure to set the Membership type to Assigned.
6. Select the users that should be part of this exclusion group and
   then select Create.

Create a Conditional Access policy that excludes the group

1. Now you can create a Conditional Access policy that uses this exclusion group.
2. In the left navigation, select Azure Active Directory and then select Conditional Access to open the Policies blade.
3. Select New policy to open the New pane.
4. Specify a name.
5. Under Assignments select Users and groups.
6. On the Include tab, select All Users.
7. On the Exclude tab, add a checkmark to Users and groups and then select Select excluded users.
8. Select the exclusion group you created.
9. Continue with setting up the Conditional Access policy based on your organizational requirements.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/conditional-access-exclusion) for the source